# Geometric realization of the mapping stack

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, topos-theory

**Some background and notation**

Let $Sh_{\infty}(Cartsp)$ be the infinity category of smooth simplicial sheaves on the site of cartesian spaces (convex open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and smooth maps between them), equipped with the topology of good open covers (contractible finite intersections).

This infinity topos is cohesive and in particular the functor ${\rm disc}:\infty-\mathscr{G}{\rm rpd}\to Sh_{\infty}(Cartsp)$ admits an $\infty$ left adjoint $\Pi$ which preserves finite products. This is the functor I am calling geometric realization.

**Question**

Let me denote the internal mapping simplicial sheaf, coming from the cartesian closed structure on $Sh_{\infty}(Cartsp)$, by $[M,X]$. Given a smooth compact manifold $M$ and a smooth simplicial sheaf $X$, I would like to compare the geometric realization of $[M,X]$ and the mapping space of the geometric realizations of $M$ and $X$ respectively. Ideally, I would hope for an equivalence 
$$\Pi[M,X]\simeq Map(\Pi(M),\Pi(X))\;.$$
Is this true? I haven't been able to come up with a counter example and I know this is true if one takes sheaves with values in a *stable* infinity category (there one can use the fact that arbitrary colimits commute with finite limits along with descent with respect to a finite cover of $M$). Any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  This question was already asked and answered on the nForum: https://nforum.ncatlab.org/discussion/6816/the-shape-of-function-objects/

Comment: Thanks! The fact that one has this 'singular nerve' representation of $\Pi$ is fantastic. Will this article be appearing on the arXiv soon?

Comment: Yes, the intention is to upload two different articles to arXiv this summer (maybe even this month) with two completely different proofs of the main result.